# treeview-like jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, plugins, jquery-plugins

I have an object for like this:

```
var obj = {
    c: {
        games: {
            game1: {
                howToPlay: { files: ['instructions.txt'] },
                files: ['characters.txt', 'wildCards.txt']
            },
            game2: { files: ['credits.txt'] }
        }
        'program files': {
            microsoft: { files: ['ieShortcuts.txt'] }
        }
        logs {
            zipped: { files: ['bigfile.txt'] },
            files: ['log1', 'log2', 'log3', 'log4', 'log5']
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I want to generate a treeview-like structure from this object I want to implement a way to select certain files (with checkboxes next to them, empty for none selected, checked for all, and filled for partially; using <img />) and have the order of files in the same folder sortable.

Something like this:

[image: Demo]

My end result is to spit back the contents of the selected files in the order that the user specified.

Is there any way to accomplish this through a jQuery plugin or combination of plugins? I started writing this from scratch but the sheer complexity seems beyond me

Comment: I know you asked about jQuery, so I'm just putting this answer as a comment. If you are developing in .NET and want a different (and potentially free option), you should look at Telerik's ASP.NET controls. They're excellent and easy to use. Otherwise, Jason's answer of jsTree is a good one. http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc/treeview.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i think [jstree](http://www.jstree.com/) is the leading treeview plugin for jquery right now.  i find it a bit clunky to use, but it gets the job done.

Comment: It's weird you got a downvote. I'll up vote you just to compensate :)

Comment: +1 - JSTree is actually pretty decent for a JavaScript solution. (See my comment to the original question as an alternative outside of jQuery.)

Comment: I just saw the checkbox plugin on the JSTree site, does it also do sortable's only in the same folder?

Comment: jstree is really flexible, have a look at the documentation only you can judge whether or not it works for you.

Comment: And is there a way to create a tree based on an object?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [TreeView component by ShieldUI](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/treeview/checkboxes).

You can customize it however you like and supports all kinds of features.